# How to import data to Core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am building an iPhone application which pulls a lot of information from an webservices that sends XML.

The problem now is that I am going to import a set of data that needs to import in 4 or 5 related tables.
It depends if the city exists in Core data.

The database looks like this: City - Club - track

The way how I would do it now is to put all the data in the database for each model.
So I would loop 4 or 5 times the data an put this in the database.
But in my head I think there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One basic document is this Apple [CoreData doc](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174) called "Efficiently importing data".
I am also building an app like yours (although on a Mac), and had implemented a very stupid importing routine which was very slow.
Following the recommendation in that document made a huge difference and made importing much, much faster!
Pay your attention in particular to the last section, "Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently".

Comment: Today I read the whole stuff. I know changed the database so I always import new data to 4 related tables.
What I did understand is that you still need to loop 4 times all the data and import that. In my case it is probably 20-40 records so it isn't that much.